# Shopping List not listing/saving more than 1 recipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

My Aim is

1. Create a shopping list which is pulling recipes from an API.
2. Take ingredients from one page to another.
3. Page to refresh/load data when more than 1 is added.

The issue I am having is

1. Only 1 set of ingredients load
2. The clear function will not allow anymore to be added.

Recipe Page

```
// Loading Recipes 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

loadDetails1(id){
    this.apiAuthentication.loadDetails(id)
    .then(data => {
        this.api = data;
    });
}

// Add to Shopping List 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

submit(api) {

    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Added to shopping list',
      duration: 1000
    });

    console.log(this.api);

    this.storage.get('myData').then((api) => {

        // add one igredient to the ingredientLines object
        // if it's still a string use JSON.parse() on it
        this.storage.set('myData', api).then(result =>{
            toast.present();
            console.log(api);
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 (click)="submit(api?.ingredientLines)">Add to shopping list</h1> 
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of api?.ingredientLines"><span>{{item}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Shopping List Page

```
getData() {
  this.storage.get('myData').then((data => {
      this.api = data;
      console.log(data);

      setInterval(() => {
        console.log(data);
      },5000);
  }));
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
            {{api?.name}}
        </ion-card-header>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let item of api?.ingredientLines">
                        <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>
                        <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <button ion-button block full color="danger" (click)="clear(item)">Remove</button>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Shopping list page looks like [image]

Error shown in visual is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDS_XTdw2S0
You can see that when I add an item to the shopping list it does not update until i close the app and restart it. Also there is only ever 1 item.

Comment: when/where is clear called?

Comment: Clear has been added

Comment: are you getting more than one line from the api? you are moving from shopping list back to recipe page to add more? Not getting the flow

Comment: Screenshot attached

Comment: Can you put a lightweight version of this use case on GIT repo? Then we can play with it no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a template to bind all of these together and create all instances as objects.

.html file

```
<template ngFor let-api [ngForOf]="shoppingList">
    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-header>
            {{api?.name}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-list inset>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let ingredient of api.ingredientLines">
                <ion-label>{{ ingredient }}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox item-right></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        <button ion-button block full color="danger" (click)="clear(api)">Remove</button>
    </ion-card>
</template>
```

and .ts file is

```
public submit(api: any) {

    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Added to shopping list',
      duration: 1000
    });

    console.log(this.api);
    var thisRecipe = this.api;

    this.storage.get('shoppingList').then((shoppingList) => {
        if(!shoppingList){
            shoppingList = [];
        }

        shoppingList.push(thisRecipe);

        this.storage.set('shoppingList', shoppingList).then(result => {
            console.log("Added to Shopping List", result);
            toast.present();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your storage that's why only 1 appears.

It should look like this, try to use [types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) and [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

```
public submit(ingredientLines: any) {

let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: 'Added to shopping list',
    duration: 1000
});

this.storage.get('myData').then((ingredientLines) => {

    console.log(ingredientLines);

    // add one igredient to the ingredientLines object
    // if it's still a string use JSON.parse() on it
    this.storage.set('myData', ingredientLines).then(result =>{
        toast.present();
    }); 
}); 
}
```

So

1. Get the data from storage
2. Apply new item to data
3. Set new data to storage

Comment: I have changed my submit function to match what you have advised, however, in my console log on click it only adds the most recent clicked? I have then looked at my console log on the shopping list page and it is still only logging 1? Is my get data correct on the shopping list page? I have also changed `ingredientLines` to `api` as I need more data than that